# Ayuda con lógica y diseño de tabla de impresoras y cartuchos

Tags: c#, sql

Buen día compañeros, soy principiante en base de datos y estoy armando una base de datos para organizar las impresoras y cartuchos de la empresa. Actualmente tengo las tablas de este modo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hatsa aqui todo bien, puedo saber la informacion completa de las impresoras y tambien manejar la informacion de los cartuchos. Pero lo que busco tambien es saber cuantas impresoras utilizan el "MODELO" de cartucho que tenga en la tabla tinta.

Ahora no se si mis tablas sean correctas, ya que por ejemplo en "tipo" guardo si la impresora es de tinta o de toner, en conexion pongo si es por USB o IP, en direcion su IP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busco que despues de existencia vaya un campo que indique la cantidad de impresoras que utilizan este "MODELO" de tinta, para saber cuantos hay que pedir al proveedor (si en existencia hay 2 y tengo 3 impresoras que utilizan este modelo entonces el pedido es 1 cartucho).

Pienso que podria hacer los calculos solo con la tabla tinta (contando los modelos) pero no hay relacion con la tabla impresora.

Comment: Me parece que te falta un campo para relacionar  ambas tablas, ¿cómo sabes cuál cartucho le corresponde a qué impresora?

Comment: Si podria quitar mis campos toner, magenta, cyan, negro y amarillo y solo poner el idtinta , pero con esto tendria 4 registros con el mismo ID de impresora y diferente id de tinta, aunque no se si esto sea lo correcto.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, es una relación muchos a muchos (una impresora puede usar varios cartuchos, y un cartucho puede funcionar en varios modelos de impresoras). Yo crearía otra tabla donde relacionaría el idimpresora y el idtinta.
Esperemos, tal vez alguien sí pueda hacer la consulta así como la quieres.

Comment: Ya realice eso pero el problema que me encuentro es que una impresora puede utilizar 4 "id" de tintas, puedo pensar que en la tabla impresora poner las llaves foraneas de los id de tinta, serian 4 llaves foraneas por impresora. Tambien cuando agrege una impresora de toner los otros 4 campos quedarian vacios y si es una impresora que utiliza cartucho tricolor. En fin  estoy batllando mucho con esta logica de que si y que no deberia tener mi tabla. Otra es crear una tabla para cada tipo de impresora y tambien para toner y cartuchos, en la tabla cartuchos "armar" el combo de juegos con un unicoID

Comment: Por eso escribí "Crear otra tabla". Tienes tu tabla impresora, y le quitas tóner, negro, amarillo, cyan, magenta. Tu tabla tinta luce bien. Ahora haces una tabla `rel_impresora_tinta`, que contendrá un consecutivo (para la pk), idimpresora (fk a impresoras) y un idtinta (fk a tintas).